# YubiKey Authenticator App doesn't recognize YubiKey after unlocking the card via PinEntry

Tags: gpg-agent, yubikey

I've got a pretty basic password/OTP set up on macOS:

- my YubiKey has the sig/aut/enc subkeys to encrypt/decrypt my passwords in the password store
- my OTPs are solely on my YubiKey - I use the Yubikey Authenticator macOS app to generate them

This setup works pretty well except for some weird issues:

- if I insert the YubiKey and I generate an OTP via the YubiKey authenticator, I can't decrypt passwords anymore as the gpg-agent/pinentry doesn't recognize the card anymore.
- if I insert the YubiKey and unlock the card to decrypt a password, the YubiKey Authenticator app no longer recognizes the YubiKey.

This results in having to unplug/plug in the YubiKey several times daily, which is annoying.

Any tips on where the issue could come from?

Comment: I forget what Yubico application it is, but at least one doesn't play nice with `gpg` and once the YubiKey is recognized in one, it can't be recognized in the other. I can't recall if it's Authenticator or not

Comment: Thanks for the answer! So this is a common thing then? I don't want to leave GPG for my passwords but I also don't want to add the OTPs directly into my password store.

Comment: I don't recall the specific Yubico GUI program, but one of them results in either the Yubico application having access to the hardware key or `gpg` having access to the hardware key, but not both _(I don't know if it's the Yubico Authenticator, but it is one of the GUI apps, as the Yubico CLI apps don't create access issues that I've found)_